# How to load es6, react, babel code in html with cdn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have [Codepen](https://codepen.io/iamanoopc/pen/vmdQGX) code that I'm trying to replicate on an web page using just three files, index.html, main.js, and style.css. I tried loading these scripts on the head tag of HTML file.

```
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/babel-transform-in-browser@6.4.6/dist/btib.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.7/react.min.js"></script>
```

However, it's not working. All I get is this error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

what are necessary CDN script files to load this react-code to HTML?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to use `babel standalone` script to transpile the code, and you need to include the script for `react and react-dom`. If you include these tags in your `<head>`, it will work:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

**Reason why it works with codepen:** check the setting/javascript, there you will find the babel is selected as **JavaScript Preprocessor**, codepen is including the script automatically, but to run these files locally you need to include the `standalone script`.

**Update:**

1- You need to define the script after the div in which you are rendering the react code, otherwise it will throw the error. like this:

```
<body> 
   <div id="root"></div> 
   <script type="text/babel" src="pomodoro.js"></script>
</body>
```

2- Use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render`.

Check the working code:

```html
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id='root'></div>
   <script type='text/babel'>
       class SetTimer extends React.Component{    
  render(){
    return (   
      <div className="set-timer">work <br/> session         
          <div className="minus-add">
            <button className="setting-button" id="minus-timer" onClick={this.props.minus}>-</button>
            <button className="setting-button" id="add-timer" onClick={this.props.add}>+</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

class SetBreak extends React.Component{
  
  render(){
    return (   
      <div className="set-break"> break<br/> session 
          <div className="minus-add">
            <button className="setting-button" id="minus-break" onClick={this.props.minusbreak}>-</button>
            <button className="setting-button" id="add-break" onClick={this.props.addbreak}>+</button>
          </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
} 

const leftPad = (time)=>{
  return (time<10)? '0'+time :time
}
const TimerDisplay = (props) => (   
  <div className="timer-display"><span className="worklabel">Work session time</span><br/>
      {props.currentTime}
      <div className="breaktime"><span className="breaklabel">break session time</span><br/>{props.breakTime}</div>
    </div>
);
// let baseTime= 25;
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      baseTime:25,
      breakTime:5,
      currentTime: moment.duration(25,'minutes'),
      timer:null,
      startbuttonvisible:true,
      pausebuttonvisible:false,
      resumebuttonvisible:false,
      stopbuttonvisible:false,
    }
    this.minus =this.minus.bind(this);
    this.add =this.add.bind(this);
    this.minusbreak =this.minusbreak.bind(this);
    this.addbreak =this.addbreak.bind(this);
    this.startTimer = this.startTimer.bind(this);
    this.pauseTimer = this.pauseTimer.bind(this);
    this.resumeTimer = this.resumeTimer.bind(this);
    this.stopTimer = this.stopTimer.bind(this);
    this.reduceTimer = this.reduceTimer.bind(this);
    
  }
  add(){
    this.setState({
      baseTime:this.state.baseTime+1
    });
  }
  minus(){
    this.setState({
      baseTime:this.state.baseTime-1
    });
  }
  addbreak(){
    this.setState({
      breakTime:this.state.breakTime+1
    });
  }
  minusbreak(){
    this.setState({
      breakTime:this.state.breakTime-1
    });
  }
  startTimer(){
    this.setState({
      timer: setInterval(this.reduceTimer, 1000), 
      startbuttonvisible:false,
      pausebuttonvisible:true,
      stopbuttonvisible:true,
    });    
  }
  pauseTimer(){
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
    this.setState({      
      pausebuttonvisible:false,
      resumebuttonvisible:true,
    });    
  }
  resumeTimer(){
    this.setState({
      timer: setInterval(this.reduceTimer, 1000), 
      startbuttonvisible:false,
      pausebuttonvisible:true,
      stopbuttonvisible:true,
      resumebuttonvisible:false,
    }); 
  }
  stopTimer(){
    clearInterval(this.state.timer);
    this.setState({
      baseTime:25,
      timer: null, 
      startbuttonvisible:true,
      pausebuttonvisible:false,
      stopbuttonvisible:false,
      resumebuttonvisible:false,
    });  
  }
  reduceTimer(){ 
    if(this.state.baseTime === 0) return;
    const newTime = this.state.baseTime - 1;
    this.setState({
      baseTime: newTime,
    });
  }
  render() {
    
    return (
      <div className="container">
         <div className="timebox">
            <div className="header">
                    Pomodoro Clock
            </div>
            <TimerDisplay currentTime={this.state.baseTime} breakTime={this.state.breakTime}/>
            <div id="action-title">
                <small>SETTINGS</small>
            </div>
            <div className="actions">
              <SetTimer minus={this.minus} add={this.add}/>
              <SetBreak minusbreak={this.minusbreak} addbreak={this.addbreak}/>
            </div>
           <div className="timer-control">
            {this.state.startbuttonvisible ? <button id="start-timer" onClick={this.startTimer}>
                START
            </button> : null}
           {this.state.pausebuttonvisible ? <button id="pause-timer" onClick={this.pauseTimer}>
                PAUSE
            </button>: null}
           {this.state.resumebuttonvisible ? <button id="resume-timer" onClick={this.resumeTimer}>
                RESUME
            </button>: null}
           {this.state.stopbuttonvisible ? <button id="stop-timer" onClick={this.stopTimer}>
                STOP
            </button>: null}
           </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Should I include the `import React from 'react'` code in the js file? I'm still not getting anything on the browser, and same error.

Comment: My index.html<br>
<code>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></scrip
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="pomodoro.js"></script>   
  </head>
  <body>
       <div id="root"></div>
</code>

Comment: promcode.js is name of the file ? you need to use type as `'text/babel'`, and inside file use `ReactDOM.render` instead of `React.render` and put this script of `promocode.js` after the <div id='root'/> in body, not in head because that react part will get rendered inside root and if you define the script before the that div it will throw the error target element not found.

Comment: Ok i did that.. now i'm getting new error `You are using the in-browser Babel transformer. Be sure to precompile your scripts for production - https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/
runScripts @ babel.js:60934
transformScriptTags @ babel.js:324
babel.js:60827 XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/admin/Desktop/test/pomodoro.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.`

Comment: check the updated answer, working code part, write in a same way it will work, just put the code in separate file and include the src.

Comment: Yep..it works. Thanks, Mayank. So I assume if I used `src/main.js` as a separate file I need to use local webserver.

Comment: check this answer of this ques, it described everything in details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838728/does-react-really-need-nodejs-on-the-frontend-env

Comment: Hi @MayankShukla I've been reading this and is in the same situation now. Was wondering why the Cross origin request error is being thrown when `script.js` is added to `index.html`. Doesn't it usually work for websites powered by Vanilla JS ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simpler example for the minimalists in the room:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <title>Minimal Static React</title>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='root'></div>

    <script type='text/babel'>
      class App extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
          super(props)
          this.state = {count: 1}
          this.increase = this.increase.bind(this)
          this.decrease = this.decrease.bind(this)
        }

        increase() {
          this.setState({'count': this.state.count+1})
        }

        decrease() {
          this.setState({'count': this.state.count-1})
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <div>
              <h1>Count: { this.state.count }</h1>
              <div onClick={this.increase}>+</div>
              <div onClick={this.decrease}>-</div>
            </div>
          )
        }
      }

      ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
<title>Beginner's Guide to React</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.3.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.3.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js">       </script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.26.0/babel.js"></script>

<script type="text/babel">
    const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');

     const element = React.createElement('div',{className:''},'Hello World' );

     ReactDOM.render(element, rootElement);

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide appropriate scripts to support React and ES6+, mentioned below:

- React and ReactDOM which can be copied from official website on page "CDN Links"  https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html
- Babel Standalone converts ECMAScript 2015+ into compatible version of JavaScript for your browser, CDN usage is described in official documentation, check babel standalone section: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html

Finally let's summarize mentioned above with simple `.html` example

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- https://reactjs.org/docs/cdn-links.html -->
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
    <!-- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/next/babel-standalone.html -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="react-container"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
        const App = () => <div>Hello!</div>
        ReactDOM.render(
        <App />, document.getElementById('react-container'))
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```