# Babel CDN link not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

Here is my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <div id="story-app"></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.3.1/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Babel -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="components.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My JS source resides in a file called components.js as below

```
class StoryBox extends React.Component { 
render() {
    return ( <div>Story Box</div> ); 
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<StoryBox />, document.getElementById('story-app')
);
```

The code is really simple and I am looking to only add a DIV to the main page but I am getting the following error in the console

```
babel.min.js:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[ÂªÂµÂºÃ€-Ã–Ã˜-Ã¶Ã¸-ËË†-Ë‘Ë -Ë¤Ë¬Ë®Í°-Í´Í¶Í·Íº-Í½Í¿Î†Îˆ-ÎŠÎŒÎŽ-Î¡Î£-ÏµÏ·-ÒÒŠ-Ô¯Ô±-Õ–Õ™Õ¡-Ö‡×-×ª×°-×²Ø -ÙŠÙ®Ù¯Ù±-Û“Û•Û¥Û¦Û®Û¯Ûº-Û¼Û¿ÜÜ’-Ü¯Ý-Þ¥Þ±ßŠ-ßªß´ßµßºà €-à •à šà ¤à ¨à¡€-à¡˜à¢ -à¢´à¢¶-à¢½à¤„-à¤¹à¤½à¥à¥˜-à¥¡à¥±-à¦€à¦…-à¦Œà¦à¦à¦“-à¦¨à¦ª-à¦°à¦²à¦¶-à¦¹à¦½à§Žà§œà§à§Ÿ-à§¡à§°à§±à¨…-à¨Šà¨à¨à¨“-à¨¨à¨ª-à¨°à¨²à¨³à¨µà¨¶à¨¸à¨¹à©™-à©œà©žà©²-à©´àª…-àªàª-àª‘àª“-àª¨àªª-àª°àª²àª³àªµ-àª¹àª½à«à« à«¡à«¹à¬…-à¬Œà¬à¬à¬“-à¬¨à¬ª-à¬°à¬²à¬³à¬µ-à¬¹à¬½à­œà­à­Ÿ-à­¡à­±à®ƒà®…-à®Šà®Ž-à®à®’-à®•à®™à®šà®œà®žà®Ÿà®£à®¤à®¨-à®ªà®®-à®¹à¯à°…-à°Œà°Ž-à°à°’-à°¨à°ª-à°¹à°½à±˜-à±šà± à±¡à²€à²…-à²Œà²Ž-à²à²’-à²¨à²ª-à²³à²µ-à²¹à²½à³žà³ à³¡à³±à³²à´…-à´Œà´Ž-à´à´’-à´ºà´½àµŽàµ”-àµ–àµŸ-àµ¡àµº-àµ¿à¶…-à¶–à¶š-à¶±à¶³-à¶»à¶½à·€-à·†à¸-à¸°à¸²à¸³à¹€-
```

Am I using the wrong link to babel.min.js? I got it from https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation from Section 3 Usage

Comment: Did you create the `.babelrc` file?

Comment: Do I need to? I am working through a basic tutorial and it doesn't mention anything. It just says once you add babel.js the code will work.

Comment: Yes, because if you read the 4th section, you can see it says: `Great! You've configured Babel but you haven't made it actually do anything. Create a .babelrc config in your project root and enable some plugins.` See if that helps, if not, I recommend using it via `npm`. It's much easier to set it up that way.

Comment: Will try that, thanks! And also appreciate you answering the question instead of condescendingly downvoting.

Comment: I'm not the one who is downvoting your question. I also do not know if you have the `.babelrc` file or not, that's why I'm using the comments.

Comment: Also in this link here: https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage in Installation it says Use it via UNPKG: https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js. This is a simple way to embed it on a webpage without having to do any other setup.

Comment: I meant to say thanks for chosing to answer the question as opposed to the others who chose to just downvote!

Comment: Strange. I've never used `Babel` this way, only via `npm`. That's why I think you need the `.babelrc` in order to make it work. But as I've read on the repository, it says that you need to specify which preset should Babel use, `<script type="text/babel" data-presets="es2015,stage-2">` that's an example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43931538/7999070, This will answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded the js file from here and it worked https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone/releases