# React js not rendering hello world

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
    <head>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="root"></div>
        <script type="text/babel">
            ReactDOM.render(
                    <h1>Hello,World!</h1>,
                    document.getElementById('root')
            );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The above code only produces a blank page looking at the console i don't see any errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your element has a `class` called *root*. You need an element with an `id` called *root*:

```
<div id="root"></div>
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/548ty2Lt/1/)**

EDIT: you will also need to add the babel-standalone module (see [this previous SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43931595/1377002)).

Comment: changed it to 'id'. Still no effect. Infact the reason i turned to class was to experiment with various settings since id dint work in the first place.

Comment: If you look at the demo it works. Something else is going wrong. Are you getting any errors in the console? How are you transpiling this? Are you using webpack, or some other means?

Comment: My snippet works perfectly with codepen but it is not working on my local browser.

Comment: [Is this link any use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931538/how-to-load-es6-react-babel-code-in-html-with-cdn)? Looks like you might need to include the babel-standalone script too.

Comment: you the real mvp.

Answer (score 0):

You said `document.getElementById('root')` but your element is a class.  Your element should have an id of root: `<div id="root"></div>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel">
      const element=<h1>Hello,World</h1>;
        ReactDOM.render(
                element,
                document.getElementById('root')
        );
    </script>
```

Run above code, main problem with you code is you have used babel and havenot added js dependency.Moreover,your are getting element by id in js but class name is defined in html.