# Vuejs Not working on IE

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, vue.js, babeljs

http://vuejs.froid.works/john

This link is perfectly working fine on chrome.  But when IE11 it shows the elements.

I tried adding babel and polyfill but no success.
http://vuejs.froid.works/john/babel.html
It is single page website. Vuejs is used as cdn in script tag. I am not using any webpack.

You can check the code by viewing its source code

Answer (score 2):

You can't use ES6 function syntax without back filling support for it with babel if you want to support browsers without ES6 support native. Why babel doesn't work for you is probably due to several things, but it doesn't  matter.

This syntax:

```
mounted() {
```

Cannot be used if you aren't transpiling it down, so instead use:

```
mounted: function() {
```

Comment: I tried 
mounted: function() {

But doing that showing compilation error

How do you suggest me use es6 with babel.
Can you send me the cdn url or both es6 and babel

Comment: @Ajay Plenty of posts on that, but check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43931538/how-to-load-es6-react-babel-code-in-html-with-cdn

Comment: I tried many solution but starts getting compilation error.
Do you want me add change that Please check this

http://vuejs.froid.works/john/babel.html