# Is it possible to use react and express but not node

Tags: reactjs, express

Can we use react with express but don't want to use node js? And how, any sample will be more helpful.

Comment: You can use _React_ without Node, but Express is a web framework _for Node_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [does react really need nodeJS on the frontend ENV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41838728/does-react-really-need-nodejs-on-the-frontend-env)